# How can I make a XAML Slider element snap to allowed values only?

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider

I have a slider with minimum value **0** and maximum value **1**.

When I currently slide it, the value gets set to a decimal value between 0 and 1, e.g. **0.2342343**.

However, I want the value to only be **either 0 or 1** (so that my ViewModel property will register the change only if it is 0 or 1 and not multiple times as the user drags it from 0 to 1).

**How can I make the slider value only be 0 or 1?** I tried SmallChange, LargeChange and SnapsToDevicePixels, but none of these work.

```
<Slider Name="TheLanguageIndexSlider"
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
        Minimum="0" 
        Maximum="1" 
        LargeChange="1"
        SmallChange="1"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        Width="100" 
        Margin="5" 
        Value="{Binding LanguageIndex}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `IsSnapToTickEnabled` to `true` and assign a value of 1 to the `TickFrequency` property:

```
<Slider IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        Maximum="1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.aspx)

```
<Slider Width="100" Value="50" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Maximum="3" TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
    AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPrecision="2" 
    Ticks="0, 1.1, 2.5, 3"/>
```

In your case:

```
<Slider Name="TheLanguageIndexSlider"
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
    Ticks="0, 1"
    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="1" 
    LargeChange="1"
    SmallChange="1"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    Width="100" 
    Margin="5" 
    Value="{Binding LanguageIndex}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```